# Authenticate from mobile apps and access file from desktop applications

Tags: android, mobile, cloud, desktop-application

We have a use case where user need to select their file on cloud storage, e.g. Google Drive and get the selected file downloaded from a desktop application whithout downloading the file to their mobile.

Is this possible? If yes, what is the possible security concern?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with getting the file ID from mobile apps, and send the file ID to my desktop application. My desktop application will build the direct link with the following format

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID
```

then begin the download with `Process.Start(DIRECT_LINK)`. This should start the download process with system browser. The only fall back for this method is that there will be no download progress reported back.